# Matplotlib: Adjust legend location/position

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, position, legend

I'm creating a figure with multiple subplots. One of these subplots is giving me some trouble, as none of the axes corners or centers are free (or can be freed up) for placing the legend. What I'd like to do is to have the legend placed somewhere in between the 'upper left' and 'center left' locations, while keeping the padding between it and the y-axis equal to the legends in the other subplots (that are placed using one of the predefined legend location keywords).

I know I can specify a custom position by using `loc=(x,y)`, but then I can't figure out how to get the padding between the legend and the y-axis to be equal to that used by the other legends. Would it be possible to somehow use the `borderaxespad` property of the first legend? Though I'm not succeeding at getting that to work.

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Edit: Here is a (very simplified) illustration of the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=False, sharey=False)
ax[0].axhline(y=1, label='one')
ax[0].axhline(y=2, label='two')
ax[0].set_ylim([0.8,3.2])
ax[0].legend(loc=2)

ax[1].axhline(y=1, label='one')
ax[1].axhline(y=2, label='two')
ax[1].axhline(y=3, label='three')
ax[1].set_ylim([0.8,3.2])
ax[1].legend(loc=2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

What I'd like is that the legend in the right plot is moved down somewhat so it no longer overlaps with the line.
As a last resort I could change the axis limits, but I would very much like to avoid that.

Comment: Can you provide a working minimal example of your code? You don't necessarily have to provide all your N subplots.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After spending way too much time on this, I've come up with the following satisfactory solution (the [Transformations Tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) definitely helped):

```
bapad = plt.rcParams['legend.borderaxespad']
fontsize = plt.rcParams['font.size']
axline = plt.rcParams['axes.linewidth']  #need this, otherwise the result will be off by a few pixels
pad_points = bapad*fontsize + axline  #padding is defined in relative to font size
pad_inches = pad_points/72.0  #convert from points to inches
pad_pixels = pad_inches*fig.dpi  #convert from inches to pixels using the figure's dpi
```

Then, I found that both of the following work and give the same value for the padding:

```
# Define inverse transform, transforms display coordinates (pixels) to axes coordinates
inv = ax[1].transAxes.inverted()
# Inverse transform two points on the display and find the relative distance
pad_axes = inv.transform((pad_pixels, 0)) - inv.transform((0,0))  
pad_xaxis = pad_axes[0]
```

or

```
# Find how may pixels there are on the x-axis
x_pixels = ax[1].transAxes.transform((1,0)) - ax[1].transAxes.transform((0,0))
# Compute the ratio between the pixel offset and the total amount of pixels 
pad_xaxis = pad_pixels/x_pixels[0]
```

And then set the legend with:

```
ax[1].legend(loc=(pad_xaxis,0.6))
```

Plot:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I saw the answer you posted and tried it out. The problem however is that it is also depended on the figure size.

Here's a new try:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = numpy.linspace(0, 10, 10000)
y = numpy.cos(x) + 2.

x_value = .014    #Offset by eye
y_value = .55

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex = False, sharey = False)
fig.set_size_inches(50,30)

ax[0].plot(x, y, label = "cos")
ax[0].set_ylim([0.8,3.2])
ax[0].legend(loc=2)

line1 ,= ax[1].plot(x,y)
ax[1].set_ylim([0.8,3.2])

axbox = ax[1].get_position()

fig.legend([line1], ["cos"], loc = (axbox.x0 + x_value, axbox.y0 + y_value))

plt.show()
```

So what I am now doing is basically getting the coordinates from the subplot. I then create the legend based on the dimensions of the entire figure. Hence, the figure size does not change anything to the legend positioning anymore.

With the values for `x_value` and `y_value` the legend can be positioned in the subplot. `x_value` has been eyeballed for a good correspondence with the "normal" legend. This value can be changed at your desire. `y_value` determines the height of the legend.

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. However, your solution does indeed depend on the size of the figure, and I would prefer a size-independent solution (I'd like to avoid having to play around with the numbers every time I have a figure of different size).
Also, what does the line `bbox = l.legendPatch.get_bbox().inverse_transformed(ax[0].transAxes)` do? I thought it would get the bounding box for the first legend, but if you plot `ax[1].legend(loc=(bbox.x0,bbox.y0))` the second legend appears at a seemingly random location.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, though I think you may have misunderstood what I said about the figure size. What I meant is that I do not want to have to eyeball any values, but use values intrinsic to the plot (axes/figure). As far as I can tell, when I change the figure size for your solution I have to re-eyeball those values, but for my solution I do not (not the x-value at least, which is what matters most to me).

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I said. `x_value` only needs to be eyeballed once (which I already did for you). The value of `.014` will always result in the padding you see in the added figure, regardless of any figure size. All I meant with the eyeballing is that you can slightly change the value if you are not happy with the padding. Again, if you want to change it because you think it might need to go to the left or right, you only need to do it once and never ever change it again. Figure size will not matter nor do you have to figure the value out.

Comment: From the matplotlib legend wiki, I did not realize I could set the legend coordinates using relative plot coordinates similar to the text command.  This was exactly what I needed: `ax.legend(loc = (0.03, 0.1))`

Comment: This doesn't actually work. If you run the posted attempted solution and zoom out on a large screen you can clearly see the x-position of the legend shift in the second subplot. (You can also see its y-position do so.) I think this may have appeared to work only because `0.014` is so close to zero.

Comment: @TheDude Also, I don't think the OP was worried about resizing the figure. The figure was ostensibly of the correct size to begin with. I think s/he only wanted to know the padding so that all the legends would be placed the same distance away from the x-axis. Therefore, the whole point was to avoid the eyeballing your method relies on.