# Matplotlib: positioning second legend relative to the first

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I would like to add two legends to one plot, and place them in the same corner, just one below the other. Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24064816/854988) I got the idea how to do this. However, I must miss something at the transformations between the different coordinate spaces. As I understand, first I get the first legend bounding box's `display coordinates`, then I convert it to `axes coordinates`, and then pass the upper right corner coordinates to the `bbox_to_anchor` param for the second legend, and tell by the `loc` param that I want these coordinates to be the lower right of the second legend (and also I can tell by `bbox_transform` that these are axes coordinates, but this should be default). So now it looks like this:

```
leg2 = ax.legend(
    lhandles2,
    llabels2,
    title = legtitle,
    labelspacing = .9,
    borderaxespad = .9,
    loc = legloc,
    prop = fp_legend,
    markerscale = 1.0,
    frameon = False,
    numpoints = 1
)

ax.add_artist(leg2)

bbleg2 = leg2.legendPatch.get_bbox().inverse_transformed(ax.transAxes)

upper_right = bbleg2.corners()[3]

leg1 = ax.legend(
    lhandles1,
    llabels1,
    labelspacing = .9,
    borderaxespad = .9,
    prop = fp_legend,
    markerscale = 1.0,
    frameon = False,
    numpoints = 1,
    loc = 'lower right',
    bbox_to_anchor =list(upper_right),
    bbox_transform = ax.transAxes
)
```

The result is totally disappointing, the second legend (`leg1` here) is missing, placed somewhere outside the plotting area. I also tried to use different transforms both at the bounding box, and at the `bbox_transform`, with no success.

Comment: Why do you want two legends?  Perhaps you can get the same effect by a single legend.  You can add legend entries without lines by just creating dummy-lines to the plot with `ax.plot([], [], 'ko', label='dummy1')` etc.

Comment: i know, anyways i generate the handles from scratch. i need 2 legends because the upper one is without title, and the lower one has a title, and the upper one is wider, and both legend frames should be aligned to the right edge of the plot.

Comment: Ok afraid I cant help you then.  However with my method, you can split it into two columns (with ncols=2) or put in a blank line (dots or line in white, without any label) in between the two groups to split them apart.